# Python regex to match identical city names but formatted differently

Tags: python, string, compare

In a Python regex, I am trying to compare identical city names that are formatted differently (uppercase/lowercase, separated by spaces or hyphens, characters with different cases). For example, "Paris" and "paris", "New York" and "neW-york" should match, but not "Paris" and "New York".

my code :

```
import re
import unicodedata


class CompareCities:
    def __init__(self):
        self.city_regex = re.compile(
            r"^(([A-Z]+[a-z]*)|([a-z]+[A-Z]*))[ -]?(([A-Z]+[a-z]*)|([a-z]+[A-Z]*))$"
        )

    def compare(self, city1, city2):

        city1_normalized = self._normalize(city1)
        city2_normalized = self._normalize(city2)

        return city1_normalized == city2_normalized

    def _normalize(self, city):
        city = (
            self.city_regex.match(city).group()
            if self.city_regex.match(city)
            else False
        )

        if not city:
            return False

        city = (
            unicodedata.normalize("NFD", city)
            .encode("ascii", "ignore")
            .decode("utf-8")
            .upper()
        )
        return city


compare_cities = CompareCities()
result = compare_cities.compare("New York", "nEw-yOrk")

if result:
    print("same city")
else:
    print("not same city")
```

the probleme , for example , "New York" and  "nEw-yOrk" should match, but not.

thank you for help

Comment: normalize your data (i.e. remove all the `-`, double spaces etc, etc etc), then do case insensitive match

Comment: Thank Marcin , I had thought of this solution, it requires me to modify/add a column in my SQL table, but it may be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def compare(city1, city2):
    city1_normalized = city1.casefold().split()  # city1  should be the actual Geographical city like Paris, New York, New Delhi
    city2_normalized = city2.casefold().split('-') # city2 can be a mixture of upper lower case and hyphens
    return city1_normalized == city2_normalized

compare("New York", "nEw-yOrk")
#True
```

Comment: thank God is One,  it seems to work. Casefold() + split(), simple and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use something else than regex, you could try instead to process the strings, by passing them all to lowercase using `.lower()` and removing any delimiter characters, such as spaces and hyphens, with `.replace()`.

There are likely some cases where two different cities differ only from a space or a hyphen, but depending on the application this might be a very small issue.

Answer (score -2):

Well, first I would suggest making the city names all lowercase (`.lower`) and then replacing all "-"s with " "s or the other way around and then doing the check—no need for overcomplicated regex.

Comment: I still don't get why I am downvoted, I was the first to respond and what I'm saying is what's done in the solution